# Clear input value on click jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to clear the input value with class "inputF" generated by the append in jQuery,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();

        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" class="inputF" name="mytext[]"/>\n\
                <button name="remove" class="remove_field">x</button>\n\
                <button name="clear" class="clear_field">clear</button>\n\
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" group="check">\n\
              </div>'),
    });

});
</script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">+</button>
<button class="show_field_button">show all</button>
```

This didn't worked for me,

```
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".clear_field", function () {
        $(this).find('.inputF').val('');
    });
```

What is the proper way to write it?

Comment: Vesion of jQuery is v1.12.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your html structure looks like

```
<div>
     <input type="text" class="inputF" name="mytext[]"/>
     <button name="remove" class="remove_field">x</button>
     <button name="clear" class="clear_field">clear</button>
     <input type="checkbox" class="check" group="check">
</div>
```

you need to use `.parent();`

```
$(wrapper).on("click", ".clear_field", function () {
     $(this).parent('div').find('.inputF').val('');
});
```

or `.closest();`

```
$(wrapper).on("click", ".clear_field", function () {
     $(this).closest('div').find('.inputF').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect selector to target sibling element:

```
$(wrapper).delegate("click", ".clear_field", function () {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.inputF').val('');
});
```

Comment: What have you changed? Isn't that exact copy of OP code

Comment: @Keyur:what version of js you are using and where are you binding the event.

Comment: @Tushar: OP was using delegate , i suggested using `.on` instead

Comment: Vesion of jQuery is v1.12.3 @MilindAnantwar

Answer (score 1):

Just replace :

```
$(this).find('.inputF').val('');
```

With :

```
$(wrapper).find('.inputF').val('');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But it is removing all textbox values. Which I don't want to.